# How do I use gnuplot to plot a simple 2d vector arrow?

Tags: gnuplot

This is my first time trying to use gnuplot, and I can't find any instructions on how to accomplish this. The closest I found was this:

> http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node259.html
>
> plot 'file.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with vectors head filled lt 2

but I can't find any explanation about "file.dat".

So can somebody give a simple example of how to draw a simple 2d vector arrow? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

gnuplot has a very good help/documentation build in. Just type `help plot` or `help vector` to learn more on how to plot vectors in gnuplot.

> The 2D `vectors` style draws a vector from (x,y) to (x+xdelta,y+ydelta).
>
> A small arrowhead is drawn at the end of each vector.
>
> > 4 columns:  x  y  xdelta  ydelta

This means, your input file should have 4 columns, where the first two columns define the starting (x,y)-position of the vector/arrow and the last two its (x,y) direction:

```
# file.dat
0   0   .5  .5
0   1   -.5 .5
1   1   1    0
```

Now typing the following command

```
plot "file.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with vectors filled head lw 3
```

gives the following output:
[image: Plotting vectors]

**Drawing vectors with the `set arrow` command**

Consider using the `set arrow` command, if you only need to draw a few vectors/arrows (e.g. to highlight some points in the plot).

```
  set arrow 1 from pi/2,1 to pi/2,0 
  set arrow 2 from pi*3/2,-1 to pi*3/2,0 
  plot[0:2*pi] sin(x)
```

[image: set arrow example]

Answer (score 1):

You can create `'file.dat'` in a spreadsheet save it as text and put it in the path of gnuplot by using the `cd` command to point gnuplot to its location. If that does not agree with you, look at the examples using `'+'` and `'++'` and `'-'` in the gnuplot manual. These are a "virtual data file." Note that the first two are for one and two column data points i.e. (x) or (x,y). You will have to use `$1` and `$2` as variables for calculating dx and dy. It is obligatory to set the `xrange` and `yrange` variables and the `isosamples` for density for this to work.

Something like....

```
set isosamples 30
set samples 30
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
plot '++' using 1:2:(0.1*sin($1)):(0.1*cos($2)) with vectors
```